# Changing Menu Tab content with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have trouble with the tab menu that... When i click on the tab menu, the content is not showing up.. (layer)

here is my fiddle demo  http://fiddle.jshell.net/By9kH/

please help me

Comment: Do you want the respective div to be shown on click of those menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `href` attributes are all the same, and the values are just a hash. This should work:

```
<li class="txt1">
    <a href="#dir1"><span>ABC</span></a> 
</li>
<li class="txt2">
    <a href="#dir2"><span>ABC</span></a> 
</li>
<li class="txt3">
    <a href="#dir3"><span>ABC</span></a> 
</li>
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/By9kH/1/

Comment: MelanciaUK / Yup~ perfectly :)